# Why is my PHP7.0-FPM pool not running using it's specified system user?

Tags: php, php-7, lxd, fpm

I've done this setup quite often but this time I'm overseeing something surely.

## Goal

Having an Apache 2.4 vhosts using different PHP-FPM pools for each vhost using their own system user within an LXD container.

## The problem

Everything is working fine except that when a file is uploaded, the upload directory must be set on www-data which shouldn't be needed in PHP-FPM.

## System

Ubuntu 16.04 LXD contianer

## Code

### /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/php7.0-fpm.conf

```html
root@web1:~# cat /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/php7.0-fpm.conf 
# Redirect to local php-fpm if mod_php is not available
<IfModule !mod_php7.c>
    # Enable http authorization headers
    SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[3457]?|t|tml)$">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
        # Deny access to raw php sources by default
        # To re-enable it's recommended to enable access to the files
        # only in specific virtual host or directory
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
    # Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
    <FilesMatch "^\.ph(p[3457]?|t|tml|ps)$">
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

### /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/hs2.nl.conf

```html
root@web1:~# cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/hs2.nl.conf 
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@hs2.nl
  ServerName hs2.nl
  ServerAlias www.hs2.nl
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/hs2.nl/web
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/hs2.nl-error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/hs2.nl-access.log combined
  #LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %{X-Forwarded-For}i" common
  <Directory /var/www/html/hs2.nl/web>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    AddHandler php7-fcgi .php
    Action php7-fcgi /php7-fcgi
    Alias /php7-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/hs2.nl-fcgi
    FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/hs2.nl-fcgi -socket /var/run/php/hs2.nl-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

### /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/hs2.nl.conf

```html
root@web1:~# cat /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/hs2.nl.conf 
[hs2.nl]
user = hs2.nl
group = hs2.nl
listen = /var/run/php/hs2.nl-fpm.sock
listen.owner = hs2.nl
listen.group = hs2.nl
prefix = /var/www/html/hs2.nl
chroot = $prefix
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```

### Directory permissions

```html
hs2.nl@web1:~/web/uploads$ ls -ald .
drwxr-xr-x 2 hs2.nl hs2.nl 2 Oct 26 15:15 .
hs2.nl@web1:~/web/uploads$ pwd
/var/www/html/hs2.nl/web/uploads
```

### Processes running as their respective user

```html
root@web1:~# ps aux | egrep "USER|php-fpm: master|pool hs2.nl"
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root     16470  0.0  0.3 365880 20220 ?        Ss   14:55   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
hs2.nl   16479  0.0  0.0 365688  4764 ?        S    14:55   0:00 php-fpm: pool hs2.nl
hs2.nl   16480  0.0  0.0 365688  4764 ?        S    14:55   0:00 php-fpm: pool hs2.nl
```

### phpinfo

```html
hs2.nl@web1:~/web$ cat phpinfo.php 
<?php
$id = shell_exec(id);
$whoami = shell_exec(whoami);
echo "Id: " . $id . "<br />";
echo "Who am I?: " . $whoami . "<br />";
phpinfo();
?>
```

#### Output

```html
Id: uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data) 
Who am I?: www-data
```

## Further thoughts

I thought it might have something to do with LXD but as it seems all pools run under their own users.

Edit: to eliminate this theory I've loaded the very same configuration onto a normal KVM virtual machine where I was able to reproduce the problem in exactly the same way so I must've done something wrong in my configuration, it's nothing to do with LXD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in Koen Reiniers' blog: http://blog.koenreiniers.nl/guide-to-combining-apache-virtual-hosts-and-php7-fpm/

Basically my fault was to have a single 'Handler' for multiple vhosts PHP-FPM sockets.

I changed my vhost config to:

```html
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
  AddHandler php7-fcgi-hs2.nl .php
  Action php7-fcgi-hs2.nl /php7-fcgi-hs2.nl
  Alias /php7-fcgi-hs2.nl /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-hs2.nl
  FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-hs2.nl -socket /run/php/php7.0-fpm.hs2.nl.sock -pass-header Authorization
  <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
  Require all granted
  </Directory>
</IfModule>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@hs2.nl
  ServerName hs2.nl
  ServerAlias www.hs2.nl
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/hs2.nl/web
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/hs2.nl-error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/hs2.nl-access.log combined
  #LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %{X-Forwarded-For}i" common
  <Directory /var/www/html/hs2.nl/web>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
      <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
          SetHandler php7-fcgi-hs2.nl
      </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

And in my PHP-FPM pool I added listen.mode = 0666:

```html
[hs2.nl]
user = hs2.nl
group = hs2.nl
listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.hs2.nl.sock
listen.owner = hs2.nl
listen.group = hs2.nl
listen.mode = 0666
;prefix = /var/www/html/hs2.nl
;chroot = $prefix
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```